# Color coding to connect rj45 socket and rj45 connector to make an ethernet extension cable

Tags: ethernet, rj45

i want to make a cable like this:

[image]

What should be the color coding to make this Ethernet LAN Network extension Cable. I have a rj45 socket and a rj45 connector but there indicator on rj45 female sockets has been removed.

[image: coding]

here is the color coding . and i was able to do it even without marking on RJ45 socket

Comment: Get a new socket that has the A or B markings still on it and use either 568A or 568B on each end.

Comment: marking is that much necessary  ??

Answer (score 1):

For cables that have been constructed to the relevant standards the colour coding is well defined by [TIA/EIA-568](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568) and the pin to pin wiring is straight through so pin1 goes to pin 1 and so on.

Comment: But don't you want to do A or B (matching) at each end, to keep the pairs right?

Comment: Of course you do.

Comment: I figured he might think you can just randomly grab colours and do or/wh as 1, then bl/wh as 2, then wh/or as 3 or whatever.

Comment: That's why I linked to the relevant standards.

Comment: [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MU_RVgTg-I 
Thank you all :) This video helped me